# Getting taxonomy name from entity for computed fields

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

Im trying to create a computed value field using the the computed_field module.  I trying to do something like http://drupal.org/node/792922 but that example is for drupal 6.  Can someone point me in the right direction of how to do this with drupal 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have taxonomy id, I'd suggest to do this:

```
$term = taxonomy_load_term($tid);
$node->your_field_name[your_language_specifier][your_value_index]['value'] = $term->name;
```

if you don't have taxonomy term id you can get it like so:

```
 $field_name = 'term'; //or what ever your field is named
 $entity_id = 4;//or what ever your entity id is   
 $query = db_select("field_data_field_" . $field_name, $field_name);
 $query->addField($field_name, "field_" . $field_name . "_tid", "tid");
 $query->condition("entity_id", $entity_id, "=");
 $result = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
 $tid = $result['tid'];
```

Comment: actually getting the taxonomy id from the entity is what I actually need the help with.

Comment: I updated the answer above with the code to get taxonomy id from an entity.